# Umbraco 4.9.0/1 Template and Razor script editors throwing errors

Tags: umbraco

I've done a manual update from 4.8.1 to 4.9.0 and then 4.9.1

I followed the manual update instructions but after updating to 4.9.0 the template and scripting files editors started throwing an error

```
Cannot create an object of type 'umbraco.uicontrols.CodeArea+EditorType' from its string representation 'HtmlMixed' for the 'CodeBase' property.

Line 226:            </cc1:PropertyPanel>
Line 227:            <cc1:PropertyPanel ID="pp_source" runat="server">
Line 228:                <cc1:CodeArea ID="editorSource" runat="server" CodeBase="HtmlMixed" EditorMimeType="text/html" ClientSaveMethod="doSubmit"
Line 229:                    AutoResize="true" OffSetX="37" OffSetY="54"/>
Line 230:            </cc1:PropertyPanel>
```

Source File: /umbraco/settings/editTemplate.aspx    Line: 228

I upgraded to 4.9.1 because of fixes needed for the media section and hoping that it would magically fix this error.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the controls.dll didn't copy properly